# Normal footnote in epigraph command

Tags: footnotes, epigraphs

I would like to create a "normal" footnote inside epigraph command.

This command cites the reference in a footnote *just below* the epigraph and not at the end of the page :

```
\epigraph{text}{source\footcite{key}}
```

For example :

```
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut}{Author\footcite{author00:_title}}
```

creates :
[image]
How can I create a normal footnote?

MWE :

```
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Book{author00:_title,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
     hyperref,
     backend=biber,
     isbn=false,
     doi=false,
     url=false,
     date=year]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\bibliography{bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut}{Author\footcite{author00:_title}}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar Sorry I updated my question. `footcite` calls `footnote` so it is the same thing. And `\footnotemark` has the same behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `\footcitetext`:

```
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
  Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut}{Author\footnotemark}
\footcitetext{author00:_title}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar I'm a great expert in `biblatex`, as you know. ;-) Just did a `ack` search for `\footcite` and I happened to find near it `\footcitetext`. *Et voilà*.

Comment: Maybe I am using this approach wrong, but here is what I am getting: 1) Footnote is bold regular size text (not footnotesize); 2) Latex commands (\textit) are included literally; 3) Hyphenation does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: @egreg I find the answer brilliant! I just have a problem, when I try to customise the footnote symbol, strange things happens, e.g. if I write `\footnotemark[\dagger]`, the first symbol ends up being a 4-digit string of numbers starting with $0$, while the footnote symbol is $0$. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Kolmin The argument to `\footnotemark` is a number, not a symbol

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for your reply| Thus, may I ask you if there is a way to get around this by getting a symbol *without* messing up your superclean solution? *[I found around some other – sort of – solutions, that are  based on the `footnote` package. However, this is apparently not a very good friend of `hyperref`, and I would really  like to avoid to get into troubles with it.]*

Comment: @Kolmin I see no other way than defining a new series of footnotes (with `bigfoot`) and defining new `\footcite` commands for using it.

Comment: @egreg Again thanks a lot for your comment! I decided to write down a  [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365602/footnote-with-special-symbol-in-epigraph-command) , because maybe it could be useful for other users as well. I will appreciate any feedback (my LatTeX ignorance is unbounded... :-) ). Again, thanks a lot!