# Footnote with special symbol in epigraph command

Tags: footnotes, epigraphs

I have a problem related to a question concerning [footnotes and epigraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154202/normal-footnote-in-epigraph-command/154207?noredirect=1#comment900815_154207).

That is, in that question the following (superclean!) answer was given by egreg:

> Just use `\footcitetext`:
>
> ```
> \epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
>   Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut}{Author\footnotemark}
> \footcitetext{author00:_title}
> ```

However, with this answer it is not possible to obtain a symbol such as `\dagger` as a footnote symbol.

Below egreg's answer I asked him clarification and he kindly pointed out that it is possible to obtain such a result by using `bigfoot`package.

How such solution should look like?

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `bigfoot` package is necessary, you could use

```
 \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

(saving - before - and restoring - after - the numeric value of the footnote counter).

For convenience, I've created two macros (`\switchfootnotenumsym` and `\switchfootnotesymnum`) for the switching between the two types of footnotes:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{author00:_title,
        author =   {Author},
        title =    {Title},
        publisher =    {Publisher},
        year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{epigraph}

% New counter for switching from numeric footnotes to the ones with symbols and vice-versa
\newcounter{tempfootnote} 
% Macro for switching from numeric footnotes to the ones with symbols
\newcommand{\switchfootnotenumsym}{%
    \setcounter{tempfootnote}{\value{footnote}} % save the current value of footnote counter
    \setcounter{footnote}{0} 
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
}
% Newcommand for switching from the footnote with symbols to the numeric ones
\newcommand{\switchfootnotesymnum}{%
    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{tempfootnote}} 
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
hyperref,
backend=biber,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
date=year]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \switchfootnotenumsym
    \setcounter{footnote}{1}% if you want the \dagger (which is the number two) set the counter to one 
    \epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut}{Author\footnotemark}
    \footcitetext{author00:_title}
    \switchfootnotesymnum

    Normal text\footnote{Normal footnote}

    \switchfootnotenumsym
    This is only to show you the correspondence between numbers and symbols (they are only 9):

    1\footnote{footnote} 2\footnote{footnote} 3\footnote{footnote} 4\footnote{footnote} 5\footnote{footnote}
    6\footnote{footnote} 7\footnote{footnote} 8\footnote{footnote} 9\footnote{footnote} 
    \switchfootnotesymnum

    Other normal text\footnote{With other normal footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[Credits to Stefan Kottwitz.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/830/101651)

*Edit:*

If you need a continuing symbol footnote counter (remember that the symbols are only 9, you will get an error if the symbol footnote counter becomes > 9):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{author00:_title,
        author =   {Author},
        title =    {Title},
        publisher =    {Publisher},
        year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{epigraph}

% New counters for switching from numeric footnotes to the ones with symbols and vice-versa
\newcounter{tempfootnotenum}
\newcounter{tempfootnotesym}
\setcounter{tempfootnotenum}{0}% initial value 
\setcounter{tempfootnotesym}{0}% initial value 

% Macro for switching from numeric footnotes to the ones with symbols
\newcommand{\switchfootnotenumsym}{%
    \setcounter{tempfootnotenum}{\value{footnote}}% save the current value of numeric footnote counter
    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{tempfootnotesym}}% restore the value of the previous symbol footnote counter
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}% set footnote with symbols
}
% Newcommand for switching from the footnote with symbols to the numeric ones
\newcommand{\switchfootnotesymnum}{%
    \setcounter{tempfootnotesym}{\value{footnote}}% save the current value of symbol footnote counter
    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{tempfootnotenum}}% restore the value of the previous numeric footnote counter
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}% set numeric footnote
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
hyperref,
backend=biber,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
date=year]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \switchfootnotenumsym
    \epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut}{Author\footnotemark}
    \footcitetext{author00:_title}
    \switchfootnotesymnum

    Normal text\footnote{Normal footnote}

    \switchfootnotenumsym
    \epigraph{We love ducks}{Author\footnotemark}
    \footcitetext{author00:_title}
    \switchfootnotesymnum

    Other normal text\footnote{With another normal footnote}

    \switchfootnotenumsym
    \epigraph{We love lions, too}{Author\footnotemark}
    \footcitetext{author00:_title}
    \switchfootnotesymnum

    I hope this is what you need\footnote{Third footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the great answer! I still have a problem. That is, now I get a symbol instead of a number, however this symbol is the first symbol that comes in the prespecified order of symbols (and that's still ok). The problem is that **this symbol** is also the very same that I get with the title. Most probably this comes from the fact that epigraph has to create a new environment and it starts to count again, not taking into account the footnote in the title. *Is it possible to fix this?*

Comment: @Kolmin If I've understood well, of course! It's enough to create a second counter where to save the "symbol footnote counter". I'll edit my answer tonight (I have no time at the moment...).

Comment: Thanks a lot, superanswer! I did not realise that the crucial issue is to use `\setcounter{footnote}{}` for symbols as well. *[An aside: the answer is really super, but there are lot of info there, in the sense that for somebody that is not supergood at LaTeX – like me... ;D – it can be a bit overwhelming, and it can become very difficult to extrapolate the relevant info.]*

Comment: @Kolmin Thank you for accepting my answer! Please tell me which part is not clear, so that I can explain it better!

Comment: Actually, there is no problem at all and everything is clear! :) I was just pointing at the fact (and mind, this is not a criticism at all!) that in a sense your answer is (a great but still) an overshooting. What I mean is that you provide a lot of info (e.g., the macro that allows to move from numbers to symbols and vice versa), while the basic answer was that first I had to use `\renewcommand` to get symbols, then I had to use `\setcounter` to pick the desired symbol (something I really didn't conceive at all – shame on me!), and finally I had to use `\renewcommand` to go back to numbers.

Comment: Thus, what I meant with my last comment of yesterday was that an answer such yours is great in absolute value, but maybe (i.e., maybe I am the only who could have troubles!) it can be problematic to somebody who is a newbie and has troubles going through the code, because you need to extrapolate the information you need from a lot of other stuff. At the end of the day, I don't know, i.e., I loved your answer, but those where just my two cents concerning the fact that sometime you have answers to newbie questions that are great, in particular for experienced users, but that happen to become...

Comment: ...great to the newbie only retrospectively, when she/he has become sort of proficient, while when the newbie receives them the first thought is "God, where should I find what I need?" (and mind that in general, when you are a newbie, you are reluctant to bother experienced people with your questions – that you basically feel are dumb – even on a site such as this that is partly related with the idea of helping each other). Anyway, thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: @Kolmin I created the macro only for convenience. It could be boring to type all the commands every time.   I hope you've learnt something new but, believe me, I'm a beginner, too!

Comment: Don't say that... :D ... if you are a beginner, I don't think there is an appropriate word on the dictionary to define my current state. Again, thanks a lot. Have a nice day!