# Footnote in epigraph with special format

Tags: footnotes, epigraphs

My problem is almost the same as this one: [Normal footnote in epigraph command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154202/normal-footnote-in-epigraph-command)

In my case, I don't want the basic display of citation.
When I use `\footcitetext{REF}`, the REF being a reference in my bibliography, for the moment it shows `NAME_OF_THE_AUTHOR YEAR`.  I'd like to have `NAME_OF_THE_AUTHOR, FIRST_NAME_OF_THE_AUTHOR: TITLE (YEAR)`

Actually I'd like to use my `\citehyperref` command, defined like this and working when used outside of an epigraph:

```latex
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citehyperref}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \bibhyperref{\usebibmacro{title}\printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}}}}    
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\printnames{author}\addcolon\space\textit{#1}\isdot}
```

Here is an example of my problem: https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=3NJ4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To place the footnotes outside the epigraph environment, you can directly use the footnote mark and then raise the data as you see fit, this is one possible way

```
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut}{Author\footnotemark}
```

\footnotetext{\cite{author00:_title}.}

Comment: I can't believe I spent 1 hour trying a lot of possibilities and looking through the documentation and not having capable of finding this solution... Thanks a lot, it works like a charm.